# Add Member to Mailchimp list via Node and Mailchimp API 3.0

Tags: node.js, npm, mailchimp

I want to add new signups in my app to a Mailchimp list. It works perfectly via a cURL statement like this:

```
curl --request POST --url 'https://us4.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/[listid]/members' --user 'anystring:[api key]-us4' --header 'content-type: application/json' --data '{"email_address":"test@example.com", "status":"subscribed","merge_fields":{"FNAME":"Freddie","LNAME":"Jones"}}' --include
```

I am using the Request module with Node.js like this:

```
var request = require('request');

request({
    url: 'https://us4.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/[list-id]/members',
    user: 'anystring:[api-key]',
    json: {
        "email_address":"test@example.com",
        "user":"anystring:[api-key]",
        "status":"subscribed",
        "merge_fields":{
            "FNAME":"Freddie",
            "LNAME":"Jones"
        }
    },
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}, function(error, response, body){
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(response.statusCode, body);
        }
    }
);
```

But I get this error:

```
401 { type: 'http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/',
title: 'API Key Missing',
status: 401,
detail: 'Your request did not include an API key.',
instance: '' }
```

How do I formulate this request properly?

Comment: BTW, I redacted the api key and list id in the code sample. In my actual request those are the real ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Went back and forth with customer support a few times and finally figured that I needed to add my API key to the ***request header*** in order to properly authenticate with the MailChimp v3.0 API. Here's the code I used:

```
request({
    url: 'https://us4.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/[list id]/members',
    json: {
        'email_address': user.email,
        'user': 'anystring:[api key]',
        'status': 'subscribed',
        'merge_fields': {
            'FNAME': user.firstName,
            'LNAME': ''
        }
    },
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'apikey [api key]'
    }
}, function(error, response, body){
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(response.statusCode, '>>>>> USER ADDED TO MAILCHIMP');
        // THEN log the user into the app
        req.login(user, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(400).send(err);
            } else {
                res.json(user);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I just compared with some code which I was recently using for accessing Mailchimp and noticed that I was supplying the API key like this:

```
var request = require('superagent'); // I am using SuperAgent

request.post(url)
.set('Authorization', 'apikey ' + apiKey) // this sets a header field
.send(data)
.end(function(err, response) {
    // ...
});
```

Note that I was using [SuperAgent](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/) instead of the Request library. You should be able to port the snippet easily though.

Essentially, the header field `Authorization` is a concatenation of the string `apikey` (trailing space) and the actual API key. Looking at the Request [documentation](https://github.com/request/request#custom-http-headers), this should work:

```
request({
    url: 'https://us4.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/[list-id]/members',
    json: json,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'apikey ' + apiKey
    }
}, function(error, response, body) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Does that mean I need to add an authorization key value to my request?

Comment: Does that look like this when concatenated: 'Authorization': 'apikey 12345apikeystringvaluehere'

Comment: Yes. (thistextisonlyforovercomingtheminimumcharlimitforanswers)

Comment: Hmmmm... not working. :( I'm also following up with Mailchimp support. I'll post an answer when I hear back. Thanks for the assistance! :)

Comment: BTW, are you using the Mailchimp v3.0 api with your SuperAgent request?

Comment: Yes, we're also using API v3. Do you still get the 401 errors? Did you also try it using SuperAgent with the first code snippet? (wasn't able to check the second code snippet).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94502/discussion-between-tonejac-and-qqilihq).

Comment: If you're using SuperAgent, just use [HTTP Basic Auth](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#basic-authentication).

Comment: @tonejac : Facing same issue. Did you got any solution for this?

Comment: @GeoJacob, I just added an updated answer. The key is using your api key in the headers of the request.

Comment: This is basically what I wrote in above's answer, isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

I use request in my [mailchimp v3 wrapper](https://github.com/thorning/node-mailchimp). I used the following for authorization with no issues:

```
request({
  method : ...,
  url : ...,
  auth : {
    user : 'any',
    password : api_key
  },
  json : ...,
  qs : ...
}
```